# Is there a Test Explorer for Playwright?

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I am looking for a tests explorer for Playwright that has a GUI, similar to what Cypress has (as shown in the screenshot). That is, an interface that allows you to visualize and run your tests, but I find that in Playwright you can only run the tests from the command line or IDE. Any leads?
[image: Cypress Test Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Playwright has that option yet. But the closest thing that you can get is the [Playwright Inspector](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#playwright-inspector).

To open the test in the Playwright Inspector UI, you have to run the command

- Debugging all Tests: `npx playwright test --debug`
- Debugging one test: `npx playwright test example --debug`

You will get a screen like this where you can visually see the test execution with test steps:

[image: Playwright Inspector]

Another Option would be the [Playwright Test](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) extension for VS Code. You can visualize the test execution like this:

[image: Test Execution]

Another option would be the [Playwright Cloud by LambdaTest](https://github.com/LambdaTest/playwright-sample/). It is a paid tool but has a free tier. But it is exactly what you are looking for:

[image: Playwright cloud]